# How to Disable the Ability to Type in a Console Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently attempting to make a snake clone in VB2015 using the console template. I'm wondering if I can disable the ability to type so I can finish it. Thank you.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5147535/4000926) from Hans Passant.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from Hans Passant's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147535/4000926):

```
while (!Done)
{
    while (Console.KeyAvailable) Console.ReadKey(true);
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: Why did you copy [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5147535/4275342) insted of mark it as dublicate? If this question is a duplicate of the question you've linked here, please flag it as a duplicate with the "flag" button under the question instead of leaving an answer to that effect. If it is not a duplicate, then please leave a complete answer instead of a link-only answer