# ReadKey gets the key pressed before being called

Tags: c#

I'm making a reaction time game. This is the code:

```
Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1000, 5000));
Console.Write("NOW: ");
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Console.ReadKey(true);
long timePassed = DateTime.Now.Ticks - start;

if (timePassed < 5_000_000) Console.WriteLine("Fast");
else Console.WriteLine("Slow");
```

The problem is that you can press the key whilst the program is sleeping and then when it is checking for keypresses it will think that you pressed the key instantly which ruins the game.

Comment: console applications aren't designed for that interactivity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147327/disabling-input-in-c-sharp-console-until-certain-task-is-completed/5147535#5147535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Console` class has a `KeyAvailable` property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable).

Right before you output `"NOW: "`, use a `while` loop with a call to `Console.KeyAvailable` (and possibly `ReadKey`) to empty the input buffer.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand. A code example would be helpfull

Comment: Sorry, I would, but I'm in a phone, on a train

Comment: `while (Console.KeyAvailable) { Console.ReadKey(true); }`